# Ever-expanding beam of light in background

Tags: background, infinite

I have a webpage, the background for which is going to be a flashlight. Is it possible to draw the flashlight so that the beam (a piece-of-pie shape) will expand, no matter the size of the user's browser? For example (love that ascii art):

```
                      /
                    /
                  /
                /
 ________/ |  /
|     _    |/
|________  |\
         \_|  \
                \
                  \
                    \
                      \
```

With the rays expanding until they hit the side of the viewport.

I don't want to use a simple image because it will be a fixed size. I was also thinking of using a Javascript drawing library like Raphael, but I don't know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an oversized background image, center it on the element and if they use an extremely large screen the effect will still work.

Comment: Wouldn't it take too long to download, especially for people with slow internet connections, or people on phones, etc?

Comment: if you keep the image simple (ie minimal gradients) the size shouldn't be bad.